# Where should I post a Windows PowerShell question?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, site-recommendation, asking-questions, superuser

Should it ask it in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) or any other site?
The question is related to how to find some files in the filesystem.

Comment: How to find files would probably work best on Super User. There's likely already a duplicate target for what you need.

Comment: On 10-Nov-2020, StackOverflow 86,411 questions vs. SuperUser 4,041 questions

Answer (score 5):

Windows PowerShell is a programming language, which is exactly what Stack Overflow is for. If you have a good question and show your research effort, your best bet will probably be SO.

Super User would work as well, as your question is about computers. I would recommend using Stack Overflow, though, because it's specifically for programming languages and there are about 64,000 questions tagged [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell), so it's definitely a well-covered topic.

Comment: Either community will work.  A good question, will require research and your own code in either community, for an appropriate answer to be submitted.  Question seeking somebody to simply write the code for you will result in the question being closed.